# JOGL debugging: DebugGL usage

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have been trying out some JOGL tutorials and in a few examples I have encountered this line of code:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
{
  GL gl = drawable.getGL();
  drawable.setGL(new DebugGL(g1));
..
```

When I look up the following this [API](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/) the DebugGL class is not defined. There is DebugGL2, DebugGL3 and its ESI variations. How do I know which one to use?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: I'm pretty sure the DebugGL classes are in a separate maven artifact, but I'm having trouble determining which...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the version of OpenGL being used by your machine. This can be found by calling the function `gl.glGetString(GL.GL_VERSION)`. From there, you can determine the appropriate DebugGL class to use.